# How to share a module using "our" variables from various sources?

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine in a module that I want to use "our" variables found in the caller. The following code does exactly what I want, but only for two previously known cases. Is there a way to do this more elegantly?

```
sub hello { # this code is in a module
  my $caller = (caller)[0];
  if ($caller eq 'main') {
    print "Hello $main::global!\n";
  } elsif ($caller eq 'Test') {
    print "Hello $Test::global!\n";
  } else {
    print "I don't know what to do!\n";
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Note that `our` variables are lexically-scoped, so you can't actually see the caller's `our` variables. (Well, you could with PadWalker.) However, you can see the see the variables in the caller's package, and the `our` variable in question is *probably* aliased to that. This is what mob's solution relies on. PS - Red pandas are the best.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying, however, if I switch from`our` to `my` it stops behaving as desired. My goal here is that there are hashes (like global, session, and user) I wish to make available to shared functions. Perhaps this is bad practice, but I feel it's okay only for this very specific purpose.

Comment: No, no need to switch to `my` for it to stop working. [Example](https://pastebin.com/g8h56kUr)

Comment: @ikegami I'm trying to learn from your postbin. Is there a line missing in the example? if I add $x to Baz.pm as `my` your example fails, but if I make it `our` it works. My Perl is v5.18.4. Might that be a factor?

Comment: No need for any changes. If you run the code as-is, it shows that mob's solution doesn't print the `our $x` the caller sees. (Feel free to add `use strict;` at the top to show that `our $x` is still in scope.)

Comment: @ikegami Ah. Confirmed. It seems that adding `use strict` is what changes things. I'm not sure I fully understand all of the stuff going on here.

Comment: No, adding `use strict;` doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: As for what's going, it's as I said above. `our $x` creates a lexical variable just like `my $x`. The difference is that the variable created by `my $x` is a fresh variable, while `our $x` aliases `$x` to the package variable of the same name in the current package. In other words, `our $x` is the same thing as `use experimental qw( refaliasing ); \my $x = \${__PACKAGE__ . '::x'};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206675/discussion-between-timothy-b-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom you are looking for is

```
no strict 'refs';
print "Hello ",${"$caller\::global"}, "!\n";
```

This construction is illegal under `use strict` so you must disable strict refs when you use it.

Comment: That works beautifully. What if the "our" variable is a hash? Does the idiom change?

Comment: For hash, I tried `print ${"$caller\::{globals->{example}}"}, "\n";` but can't get it to work.

Comment: The hash is `%{"$caller\::globals"}` and the element is`${"$caller\::globals"}{"example"}`

Comment: I spent a few hours googling and trying different idioms without success before resorting to a followup question. It's hard to google when you don't actually know what it's called. Is this symbolic referencing? In any case, these are life savers and do exactly what I want. Thanks!